# Using Filevault 2 (encrypted hard drive) with Git

Tags: macos, git, security, encryption

I want to encrypt the hard drive on my mac using filevault 2 to secure my code while travelling. The code is under version control (git, with smartGit). Will there be any problems with the version control after i encrypt my hard drive?

Would you recommend any other means for security instead/complimentary to this action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileVault 2 is completely transparent, and will not affect the operation of any user-level program. I know this, because I've used it on my computer for a long time, and I know that git works without any issues. :-)